# Visual Studio Build Event / Target for Build New Version

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like to catch the event for Build New Version during the Build Process (See Screenshot)

Does anyone have a advice how to realize this? Any suggestion or link would be helpful.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SamRl.png)

Comment: This is not a standard VS feature, you'll have to get support from the author/vendor of the extension you are using.  I'd guess you want to use [this page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrecisionInfinity.AutomaticVersions#qna), but it is a guess.

Comment: Oh great thank you so much! Now I undestand why I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you make your comment as a Answer so I can Close this Question.

Comment: It was just a guess, I'm none the wiser from your comments.  Just share what you discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.